# Compiling a C program for a pic microcontroller - error message

Tags: c, microcontroller, pic

I have a C program that I am trying to put on my pic but I get the error "3.17 can't open include file "main.h": No such file or directory". This is my first time ever attempting to program a pic.

Here is the program I am trying to put on it.

```
#include <htc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "main.h"

__CONFIG(FOSC_INTOSC & WDTE_OFF & PWRTE_OFF & MCLRE_ON & CP_OFF & CPD_OFF & BOREN_OFF & CLKOUTEN_OFF & IESO_OFF & FCMEN_OFF);
__CONFIG(WRT_OFF & PLLEN_OFF & STVREN_OFF & BORV_HI & LVP_OFF);

#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000

int main()
{
  int     t = 0;
  char    outStr[8];
  char    ch;

  init();

  Lcd_PutStr(0, 0, "Option 1");
  Lcd_PutStr(1, 0, "Spec Analyzer");

  while (1)
  {
    // do stuff here
  }
}

int init()
{
    // Hardware
    OSCCON = 0x6A;        // 4 MHz oscillator

    PORTA = 0;          // Clear Port A
    LATA = 0;

    PORTB = 0;          // Clear Port B
    LATB = 0;

    PORTC = 0;          // Clear Port C
    LATC = 0;

    ANSELA = 0;         // Set Port A to digital
    ANSELB = 0;         // Set Port B to digital
    ANSELC = 0;         // Set Port C to digital

    TRISB = 0;          // Set port B to output
    TRISC = 0;          // Set port C to output

    // LCD display
    Lcd_Init();

    return 0;
}

void ENPulse()
{
  LATC |= 0x20;
  __delay_us(1);
  LATC &= 0xdf;
}

void Lcd_Init()
{
    LATC = 0;
    __delay_ms(40);

    LATC = 0x03;
    ENPulse();
    __delay_us(37);

    Lcd_Cmd(0x28);
    __delay_us(37);

    Lcd_Cmd(0x28);
    __delay_us(37);

    Lcd_Cmd(0x0C);
    __delay_ms(2);

    Lcd_Cmd(0x01);
    __delay_us(37);
}

void Lcd_Cmd(byte cmd)
{
    LATC = cmd >> 4;
    ENPulse();
    LATC = cmd & 0x0F;      // clear RS (LATC,4)
    ENPulse();
    __delay_us(100);
}

void Lcd_Data(byte data)
{
    LATC = (data >> 4) | 0x10;    // set RS (LATC,4)
    ENPulse();
    LATC = (data & 0x0F) | 0x10;  // set RS (LATC,4)
    ENPulse();
    __delay_us(100);
}

void Lcd_PutStr(int row, int col, char* str)
{
    int   pos;

    // use row and column=-1 for no positioning, i.e. position where last ended
    if (row >= 0 && col >= 0)
    {
        if (row > 0)
            row = 0x40; // row 1
        else
            row = 0;  // row 0

        pos = row | col | 0x80;   // 0x80 is cmd for positioning cursor
        Lcd_Cmd(pos);
    }

    while (*str)
    {
        Lcd_Data(*str);
        str++;
    }
}
```

I am using MPLab and Hi-Tech C with a Pickit3. I based this code off of a sample given to me. I do not know what the purpose of the main.h file is. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is there a file named "main.h" in the directory with "main.c"? If not, you need to get main.h from the same place you got main.c

Comment: I do not know. I guess what I need the most is to understand what main.h is supposed to contain.

Comment: Can you comment it out and see if it compiles?

Comment: As, Dom says, comment out the include and see what the compiler tells you. Then you will know how to fill it in.

Comment: Ok. I commented it out and received the following errors. Warning [361] C:\Users\School\Documents\pic.c; 16.1 function declared implicit int
Warning [361] C:\Users\School\Documents\pic.c; 18.1 function declared implicit int
Warning [361] C:\Users\School\Documents\pic.c; 49.1 function declared implicit int
Error   [984] C:\Users\School\Documents\pic.c; 62.1 type redeclared
Error   [1098] C:\Users\School\Documents\pic.c; 62.1 conflicting declarations for variable "Lcd_Init" (C:\Users\School\Documents\pic.c:49)
Warning [361] C:\Users\School\Documents\pic.c; 70.1 function declared implicit int

Comment: Error   [372] C:\Users\School\Documents\pic.c; 83.19 "," expected
Error   [984] C:\Users\School\Documents\pic.c; 84.1 type redeclared
Error   [1098] C:\Users\School\Documents\pic.c; 84.1 conflicting declarations for variable "Lcd_Cmd" (C:\Users\School\Documents\pic.c:70)
Error   [372] C:\Users\School\Documents\pic.c; 92.20 "," expected
Warning [349] C:\Users\School\Documents\pic.c; 93.1 non-prototyped function declaration for "Lcd_Data"
Error   [984] C:\Users\School\Documents\pic.c; 102.1 type redeclared

Comment: Error   [1098] C:\Users\School\Documents\pic.c; 102.1 conflicting declarations for variable "Lcd_PutStr" (C:\Users\School\Documents\pic.c:18)

Comment: Yeah, you need that main.h file. You could try and prototype the functions below your main and see if that helps reduce the errors. Do you know how to prototype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing your errors, you may be able to run the code without main.h. It looks like main.h mostly prototypes the functions at the bottom of the file. Try putting this code between the main and the #define:

```
int init();
void ENPulse();
void Lcd_Init();
void Lcd_Cmd(byte cmd);
void Lcd_Data(byte data);
void Lcd_PutStr(int row, int col, char* str);
```

This should at lest reduce most of your errors. It may fix it completely. The idea is that when the compiler first encounters theses functions it doesn't know what they are and it throws errors before it can find them. If there are still errors let me know and I'll try and help more.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did as you suggested but I am still getting these errors: Error   [372] C:\Users\School\Documents\pic.c; 12.19 "," expected
Warning [349] C:\Users\School\Documents\pic.c; 12.23 non-prototyped function declaration for "Lcd_Cmd"
Error   [313] C:\Users\School\Documents\pic.c; 12.23 function body expected
Error   [372] C:\Users\School\Documents\pic.c; 13.20 "," expected
Warning [349] C:\Users\School\Documents\pic.c; 13.25 non-prototyped function declaration for "Lcd_Data"

Comment: Error   [313] C:\Users\School\Documents\pic.c; 13.25 function body expected
Warning [359] C:\Users\School\Documents\pic.c; 28.28 illegal conversion between pointer types
pointer to const unsigned char -> pointer to unsigned char
Warning [359] C:\Users\School\Documents\pic.c; 29.33 illegal conversion between pointer types
pointer to const unsigned char -> pointer to unsigned char
Error   [372] C:\Users\School\Documents\pic.c; 93.19 "," expected
Error   [372] C:\Users\School\Documents\pic.c; 102.20 "," expected

Comment: Basically my desired functionality is to have a push button that toggles through a list and display them on an LCD screen.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it looks like the main.h file is necessary. You may be able to do a workaround, but you would need to fix all the errors one by one. It looks like the amount was reduced though and most are just warnings which it will only complain about, but it will compile.

Comment: Thank you for your help. There are tons of things I can do with the pic so I am excited to learn!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```c
#include <htc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
//#include "main.h"

__CONFIG(FOSC_INTOSC & WDTE_OFF & PWRTE_OFF & MCLRE_ON & CP_OFF & CPD_OFF & BOREN_OFF & CLKOUTEN_OFF & IESO_OFF & FCMEN_OFF);
__CONFIG(WRT_OFF & PLLEN_OFF & STVREN_OFF & BORV_HI & LVP_OFF);

#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000



int init()
{
    // Hardware
    OSCCON = 0x6A;        // 4 MHz oscillator

    PORTA = 0;          // Clear Port A
    LATA = 0;

    PORTB = 0;          // Clear Port B
    LATB = 0;

    PORTC = 0;          // Clear Port C
    LATC = 0;

    ANSELA = 0;         // Set Port A to digital
    ANSELB = 0;         // Set Port B to digital
    ANSELC = 0;         // Set Port C to digital

    TRISB = 0;          // Set port B to output
    TRISC = 0;          // Set port C to output

    // LCD display
    Lcd_Init();

    return 0;
}

void ENPulse()
{
  LATC |= 0x20;
  __delay_us(1);
  LATC &= 0xdf;
}

void Lcd_Init()
{
    LATC = 0;
    __delay_ms(40);

    LATC = 0x03;
    ENPulse();
    __delay_us(37);

    Lcd_Cmd(0x28);
    __delay_us(37);

    Lcd_Cmd(0x28);
    __delay_us(37);

    Lcd_Cmd(0x0C);
    __delay_ms(2);

    Lcd_Cmd(0x01);
    __delay_us(37);
}

void Lcd_Cmd(byte cmd)
{
    LATC = cmd >> 4;
    ENPulse();
    LATC = cmd & 0x0F;      // clear RS (LATC,4)
    ENPulse();
    __delay_us(100);
}

void Lcd_Data(byte data)
{
    LATC = (data >> 4) | 0x10;    // set RS (LATC,4)
    ENPulse();
    LATC = (data & 0x0F) | 0x10;  // set RS (LATC,4)
    ENPulse();
    __delay_us(100);
}

void Lcd_PutStr(int row, int col, char* str)
{
    int   pos;

    // use row and column=-1 for no positioning, i.e. position where last ended
    if (row >= 0 && col >= 0)
    {
        if (row > 0)
            row = 0x40; // row 1
        else
            row = 0;  // row 0

        pos = row | col | 0x80;   // 0x80 is cmd for positioning cursor
        Lcd_Cmd(pos);
    }

    while (*str)
    {
        Lcd_Data(*str);
        str++;
    }
}

int main()
{
  int     t = 0;
  char    outStr[8];
  char    ch;

  init();

  Lcd_PutStr(0, 0, "Option 1");
  Lcd_PutStr(1, 0, "Spec Analyzer");

  while (1)
  {
    // do stuff here
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I eventually got it to work. I just needed to add the voids to a .h file and also add the .h file to the Header section in MPLab.